# How to change the default log in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5

Laravel 5 only has one place to configure logging. You can specify if you want daily log files or a single log file.

I want to use my own monolog instance, but I can't seem to figure out what the proper place is to assign it to Laravel Log writer.

I want to be able to keep using the Log facade.

In my search I have stumbled upon http://laravel.io/forum/02-11-2014-howto-log-with-mongodb, so I have an idea on how to implement this, but the forum post is written for Laravel 4. In Laravel 5 there is no `app/start/global.php` anymore and I am searching for the proper place for this code.

Is this something you should do as middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging`. This is where logging gets setup.

Specifically the `registerLogger()` method. Notice how it sets up `$app['log']`:

```
$app->instance('log', $log = new Writer(
    new Monolog($app->environment()), $app['events'])
);
```

So what I would do is edit your `AppServiceProvider` (or create a new `LogServiceProvider`, your preference) and overwrite this.

```
$app->instance('log', new \Illuminate\Log\Writer(
    new Monolog\Logger(... however you want to setup Monolog ...)
);
```

The `Log` facade simply accesses `$app['log']`. So once you've overridden that, you're all set.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have moved the logging to it's own package with it's own configuration, so a LogServiceProvider now seems the obvious way to do it. Thanks for pointing out how to do this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by overriding the Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging class. Small write up on how: [Configuring Custom Logs in Laravel 5](https://blog.muya.co.ke/configure-custom-logging-in-laravel-5/)

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist' in /home/vagrant/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:741
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(741): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 /home/vagrant/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)